# Map vs fold memory usage in OCaml

Tags: memory, ocaml

What is the impact on memory usage while folding over a list/array and how it compares to memory usage when list or array is mapped (I mean performing something like `List.map f l` ) ?

I would have guessed that folding is more expensive since it creates "new" result with each iteration and map can be preallocated beforehand but on the other hand map is not tail-recursive.

For the sake of simplicity let us consider the following example:

```
let lol = List.init 1000 (fun _ -> List.init 1000 (fun j-> j) );;

let fold_left_res = List.fold_left (fun res l -> List.map (fun e -> e + 1) l :: res) lol  [] ;;

let map_res = List.map (fun l -> List.map (fun e -> e + 1) l) lol ;;

let fold_right_res = List.fold_right (fun l res -> List.map (fun e -> e + 1) l :: res) lol  [];;
```

Using `spacetime` I've profiled the program and obtained the following results:

1. After the list initialization:

Live bytes: 22MB Live blocks:1.0M All allocated words:3.0M

2. After fold_left:

Same thing as after list initialization (why?)

3. After map

Live bytes: 44MB Live blocks:2.0M All allocated words:6.0M

4. After fold_right

Live bytes: 64MB Live blocks:3.0M All allocated words:9.0M

Why does `fold_left` seem to not reserve additional memory ?
And why `lol` consumes so much memory in the first place ?

Update 1. Prepared a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you talk about memory usage you're talking about the heap. As you noticed, the stack and the heap are two different things.

For the stack, both List.map and List.fold_right are documented as not being tail recursive. (See the [List module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.10/libref/List.html) documentation.) So your test results are in line with what one would expect.

Since a fold can basically do anything at all, depending on the nature of the accumulated result, it's not really possible to say anything definitive about the heap usage as far as I can see.

For a map, the usual behavior is to return independent (distinct) newly computed values for each of the elements of the input list. So you could say that it will allocate N * K amount of heap storage, where N is the length of the list and K is the size of one of the computed values. But in reality, the map function can also do almost anything. It doesn't even have to allocate new values, that's just a rough generalization. Maybe this is what you mean when you say that map can be precomputed beforehand.

If you're talking about the spine of the returned list, this can't really be calculated beforehand. Lists are immutable, and every call to List.map creates a new list (the spine of the result).

Comment: By "List.map creates a new list for every call" you mean every application of a function `f` to an element of `l` in `List.map f l` ?

Comment: The return value of `List.map` is a list. If you imagine a list as a "spine" with values hanging from it like a necklace, the spine of the return value of `List.map` is a newly created list. The values hanging from the new list are the values returned by the separate calls to `f`. So no, every call to `f` doesn't create a new list.

Comment: Could you please specify then, what did you mean by "List.map creates a new list (the spine of the result) for every call." ?